# Метрика при поиске по сетке

Tags: python-2.x, дерево, классификация

Доброго времени суток. Я хочу организовать поиск по сетке `GridSearchCV` чтобы подобрать оптимальные параметры для классификатора `ExtraTreesClassifier`. В качестве метрики меня интересует критерий Джинни (то есть я хотела бы получить параметры для моего классификатора, опираясь на Джинни). Но в описании (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html) его нету. Как можно задать свою метрику и можно ли?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вполне себе можно.

Посмотрите пункт *Defining your scoring strategy from metric functions* в [документации](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html).

Пример (*l_inf-норма*):

```
import numpy as np
def my_custom_loss_func(ground_truth, predictions):
    diff = np.abs(ground_truth - predictions).max()
    return np.log(1 + diff)
```